# Symmetric polynomials - real versus complex...

Tags: symmetric-polynomials, several-complex-variables

**Context:** Inspired by a recent question I found a very cute proof that the zero set of a complex polynomial depends continuously on the polynomial.  (Yes, there's some question regarding what that even *means*; will clarify that if and when I talk about it - this post is about something else.) Just realized there's a problem with the argument - this question is about fixing that.

Say $p_0,\dots p_d$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials in $d$ variables. We all know that if $p\in\Bbb C[z_1,\dots,z_d]$ is symmetric then there exists a polynomial P such that $$p=P(p_0,\dots,p_d).$$

So far these polynomials are what I think of as holomorphic polynomials on $\Bbb C^d$. **Now** suppose instead that $p$ is a "real polynomial" on $\Bbb C^d$:
$$p=p(z_1,\dots,z_d;\overline z_1,\dots,\overline z_d).$$And suppose $p$ is symmetric, *in* the sense that $$p(z_1,\dots,z_d;\overline z_1,\dots,\overline z_d)=p(z_{\sigma(1)},\dots,z_{\sigma(d)};\overline z_{\sigma(1)},\dots,\overline z_{\sigma(d)})\quad(\sigma\in S_d).$$

**Question:** Does it follow that there exists a polynomial $P$ such that $$p=P(p_0,\dots,p_d;\overline p_0,\dots,\overline p_d)?$$

**Note:** Of course we could just as well say $$p=p(x_1,\dots,x_d;y_1,\dots,y_d).$$But $p$ is not invariant under an arbitrary permutation of $(x_j,y_j)$, just under the subgroup of $S_{2d}$ that maps $(x_j)$ to itself and then applies the same permutation to $(y_j)$.

(**My work so far:** No clue. Maybe it's true; I can imagine some sort of "algebraic" Stone-Weierstrass on $\Bbb C^2/S_d$. Otoh if it's true it should be clear for, say, $d=2$ and $p(z)=|z|^2$; I get as far as $$|z|^2=(z_1+z_2)(\overline{z_1+z_2})-(z_1\overline z_2+\overline z_1z_2)$$and I'm stuck. If it's false I bet that's a counterexample...)

Comment: Don't the monomials $1, z_i, \overline{z_j}, z_iz_j, \overline{z_i}z_j, \overline{z_i}\overline{z_j}$ form a basis of the polynomials in $z_i, \overline{z_i}$ of degree at most $2$? Then  $p_0$, $p_1$, $p_1^2$, $p_2$, $\overline{p_0}$, $\overline{p_1}$, $\overline{p_1^2}$, $\overline{p_2}$ are in the span of the subset of the basis that excludes the $\overline{z_i}z_j$? So $z_1\overline{z_2} + \overline{z_1}z_2$ will not be in the subalgebra generated by the $p_i$ and $\overline{p_i}$.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes and yes. Probably I'm just being stupid, but I don't see how that implies that $z_1\overline z_2+\overline z_1z_2$ is not in the algebra generated by the $p_j$ and $\overline p_j$...

Comment: I was thinking that the $\overline{p_j}$ had to be algebraically independent over $\Bbb{C}[p_j]$ in the same way as the $p_j$ are algebraically independent over $\Bbb{C}$ (so that the grading by degree would imply you couldn't get a degree $2$ polynomial other than one in the span of $p_0 \ldots \overline{p_2}$ (as listed above)). However, on reflection, it's not obvious that the $\overline{p_j}$ are algebraically independent over $\Bbb{C}[p_j]$.

Comment: @RobArthan Thanks. I can stop wondering whether I'm missing something _totally_ obvious then. Guessing what algebraic independence means (don't bother, I can look it up) yes, that does sound like more or less what I didn't/don't see...